# Появление элементов с помощью fadeIn по очереди

Tags: jquery, анимация

Есть несколько элементов с классом `test`.
Для них я использую `$('.test').fadeIn('slow');`.
Как сделать так, чтобы элементы появлялись по очереди?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При задании продолжительности в виде числа, можно воспользоваться различной задержкой (с помощью метода `delay`) для каждого элемента:

```js
var duration = 600; //'slow'
$(".test").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(duration * index).fadeIn(duration);
});
```

```css
.test {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">First</div>
<div class="test">Second</div>
<div class="test">Third</div>
<div class="test">Forth</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```